# How to store general data of a application in mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

i am working on a app inwhich anyone can purchase a product
when one place his order there is some extra charges added i.e minimum delivery charge, GST, and these values are gereral data of my app, i just want to read and calculate accordingly,
i want to store some data in the mongodb database
and i dont want to make multiple document of these data.
just want to read and update

data like =>
currentGST:18%,
minDeliveryCharge:100,
appVersion:"1.0.0",
appName:"MyAwesomeApp",
appSlogan:"Some Beautiful Slogan",

i handle it by creating a schema with these field
and put a single document in it
i read it by findOne() and limit(1) then document.currentGST
and i don't thing this is the standard way.
is there any standard way of doing this
by which i can simply store data without creating multiple documents
may be i am unable to describe my problem,sorry for that.

Any help appriciated, THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a Schema for all the values required for look-up. The Schema will have two fields, the label which will be an String and the value which can also be a string.
You may also save timeStamps.

here is how it can be done...

```
const generalDataSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
label:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
value:{
    type:String,
    required:true
} },{timeStamps:true});
```